# How to compare dates using Ebean in Play Framework?

Tags: java, orm, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

`Scenario.java`:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.ebean.*;

@Entity
public class Scenario extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public boolean isPublic;
    public boolean isAccepted;
    public Date expirationDate;
    @ManyToOne
    public User owner;
    @ManyToMany
    public List<User> members = new ArrayList<User>(); 
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Checkpoint> checkpoints = new ArrayList<Checkpoint>();

    public static Model.Finder<Long, Scenario> find =
            new Finder<Long, Scenario>(Long.class, Scenario.class);

    public Scenario(String name, boolean isPublic, Date expirationDate, User owner) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isPublic = isPublic;
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.isAccepted = false;
        this.members.add(owner);
    }

    public static Scenario create(String name, boolean isPublic, Date expirationDate,
            String owner) {
        Scenario scenario = new Scenario(name, isPublic, expirationDate, User.find.ref(owner));
        scenario.save();
        scenario.saveManyToManyAssociations("members");
        return scenario;
    }

    public static List<Scenario> findNotExpired(Date date) {
        return find.where().or(
                com.avaje.ebean.Expr.lt("expirationDate", date),
                com.avaje.ebean.Expr.isNull("expirationDate")
                ).findList();
    }
}
```

The test:

```
@Test
    public void findScenariosNotExpired() {
        new User("bob@gmail.com", "Bob", "secret").save();
        new User("jane@gmail.com", "Jane", "secret").save();
        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"); 
        Scenario.create("Scenario 1", false, null, "bob@gmail.com");
        try {
            Scenario.create("Scenario 2", false, dt.parse("2013-12-12 00:00:00"), "jane@gmail.com");
            Scenario.create("Scenario 3", false, dt.parse("2013-10-10 00:00:00"), "jane@gmail.com");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem with date parsing");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Scenario> results = Scenario.findNotExpired(new Date());
        assertEquals(2, results.size());
    }
```

The test's result:

```
[error] Test models.ModelsTest.findScenariosNotExpired failed: expected:<2> but was:<3>
```

In the test I pass `new Date()` as it should include today's date (Oct 13, 2013). That's why I expect the size of 2 (one null and one date before today).

What should I change? I guess the problem could be with `com.avaje.ebean.Expr.lt("expirationDate", date)` - is it OK to compare date like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `MM` instead of `mm`.

Using

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");

dt.parse("2013-12-12 00:00:00") evaluates to Sat Jan 12 00:00:00 EST 2013

dt.parse("2013-10-10 00:00:00") evaluates to Thu Jan 10 00:00:00 EST 2013
```

Instead use,

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: for the hour, note that "h" gives you the 12-hour format. Use "HH" in place of "hh" to get the hour in 24-hour format. Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html